# Convert IConfiguration to ConfigurationManager

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am currently converting a net-framework project to a net-core project.

For this I need the App.Config, which I created in the Core-Project as appsettings.json.

In the old project the configuration-call takes place as follows.

```
MyClass settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sectionname") as MyClass;
```

(Fork from https://github.com/Azure/azure-relay/tree/master/samples/hybrid-connections/dotnet/portbridge/PortBridgeClientAgent)

I'm already using the ConfigurationBuilder for net-core.

But I have to convert the IConfiguration as ConfigurationManager, don't I? How?

Thanks in advance.

```
ConfigurationManager manager = configuration;
```

Says: "Cannot implicitly convert type IConfiguration to ConfigurationManager". An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Configuration is very different within .net core, take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: `var manager = configuration;`

Comment: Thanks for advice. Could you please take a look at the PortBridgeAgentSection.cs in the link. So do I need to recycle this class? (its using ConfigurationProperty)

Comment: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is now available as [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) even for dotnet core projects.